# Matching the font in math mode to the "Huge" font in text mode

Tags: math-mode, bold

In this simple code, I am just trying to match the font of the "$a$" in math mode to the `\Huge` font in which I have "-labels" typeset.

I assume that an analogous command would be used if I replace `\Huge` with `\Large`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}




\begin{document}




\centerline{\boldmath$a$\unboldmath-\Huge\textbf{-labels}} \vskip0.3in



\end{document}
```

Comment: By "matching the font," are you referring to the font *size*? That is, the `$a$` should be the same height as the `a` in `-labels` (that is `\Huge` or whatever)?

Comment: @Werner Yes, I am intending only the size. I want to keep the "$a$" in its math italic font and the hyphen and "labels" in their upright Roman font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools,bm}




\begin{document}




\centerline{\Huge{\boldmath$a$}\textbf{-labels}} \vskip0.3in

or simpler

\centerline{\Huge$\bm{a}$\textbf{-labels}} \vskip0.3in

\end{document}
```

Comment: note neither `\centerline` nor `\vskip` should appear in a latex document, `\begin{center}` would be the latex form

Comment: Why is `\begin{center}` preferred to `\centerline`? I see the latter in the code of other users more often than I see the former. With what would you suggest that I replace my `\vskip` command?

Comment: @user143462 neither vskip nor centerline are documented latex commands, neither even gets  a mention in the latex book. `\vskip` does not have latex syntax and should be replaced by `\vspace{..}`. `\centerline`  is actually defined in the latex sources but as an undocumented copy over from plain tex , it does not match the behavour of any latex box command as it is a raw `\hbox`  unguarded by `\leavevmode`